# Nightwatch - WaitForElementVisible and click failed

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

I have read somme issue about waitForElementPresent and the click action, but I don't anderstand how to make it work better.. 
I Explain :
I have list where I have to select an element, and bellow I have a element to click. To do that, I put a WaitForElementVisible and a command click, but it does not always work, because the list above is not always closed.

My nightwatch code :
[image: The NightWatch code]

Below the code of the page :
It concern select name = cdNatuVoie for the list and input id = nmVoie

[image: The code of this elements]

Why the command waitForElementVisible don't work that ?

Thanks,

Comment: which line breaks ?

Comment: Hello,This is the line :

`onglet_caracteristiques_generale.click('@select_qualiteOccupant', function(response) {
      console.log('Clic sur select_qualiteOccupant', JSON.stringify( response, null, 2));
      browser.pause(3000);
      });`